# Is there any visa stamp issue with Concurrent H1B?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I have a H1B from my full-time employer. Now, with inflation is at highest level in this corona stage, the only way to increase income is to find extra work.

I was checking to find out about a Concurrent H1B. There are some references below.

As per my reading, we will have 2 W2 forms, meaning we are earning more and paying more taxes. For that reason, there should be no legal issue as long as you pay your taxes.

I want to know if anyone has faced any issue in visa stamping?

I might take advice from an immigration attorney to know if is there any clause in my current full-time job offer later that **I can't work for any other company**, but before that, I am looking if someone has done this.

*What is Concurrent H1B?*

- https://www.visapro.com/resources/article/concurrent-h1b/
- https://ustunlawgroup.com/things-you-should-know-about-filing-concurrent-h-1b-and-working-for-two-employers/
- https://www.am22tech.com/concurrent-h1b-multiple-jobs/

Comment: "IMPORTANT
USCIS may not approve a H1B concurrent employment for a full-time position if the employee is already working full-time for the main H1B employer."  Are you currently working part time?

Comment: I read that, I am full-time employee and I might be apply for part time concurrent H1B.

Comment: Inflation is negligible. If you can't make ends meet, your employer is paying much less than a reasonable salary. Is he using the H1B program to avoid paying American-level wages?

Comment: nope it is, but looking for some extra :). Want to buy house, which was 250K last April now its 354K. Want to look for getting extra now.